# Slowly vanishing sequences $a_n$ with $\sum a_n^p$ divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

One cute way to prove that a sequence $a_n$ of non-negative reals converges to zero is to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^p < \infty$$ 
for some fixed (large) $p$. (For then $a_n^p \to 0$ and thus $a_n \to 0$.)

This technique can fail if $a_n \to 0$ *really slowly*, like for the sequence $a_n = 1/\log n$: we have $\log^p n = o(n)$ so eventually $a_n^p$ exceeds $1/n$.

**Question**. If $a_n \searrow 0$ but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^p$ diverges for all $p > 1$, is $a_n$ eventually bounded below by $1/\log n$? What if we remove the monotonicity assumption?

By "eventually bounded below" I mean $\displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty}\,\,a_n \log n > 0$.

Comment: You should take exponents into account. Clearly $a_n = (\log n)^{-\alpha}$ works for all $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: @MahbubAlam What do you mean?

Comment: If we take $a_n=\frac{1}{\log \log n}$ then $a_n$ converges to zero rather slowly. But that not a answer to the question $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}$ will work. I mean this isn't eventually bounded below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from $\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\alpha}}$ (for $n > 1$) which decreases faster than $\frac{1}{\log n}$ for $\alpha > 1$, for $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, the sequences

$$a_n = \exp \bigl( - (\log n)^{\varepsilon}\bigr)$$

decrease faster than any power of $\frac{1}{\log n}$, and slower than any power of $\frac{1}{n}$, so we have

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n^p = +\infty$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n(\log n)^{\alpha} = 0$$

for all $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ and $\alpha > 0$.

So the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: Yeah! Duh! I should think a little before asking! Thanks.